# Is there a way to make this C++14 recursive template shorter in C++17?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

This `poly_eval` function will compute the result of evaluating a polynomial with a particular set of coefficients at a particular value of x. For example, `poly_eval(5, 1, -2, -1)` computes x^2 - 2x - 1 with x = 5. It's all `constexpr` so if you give it constants it will compute the answer at compile time.

It currently uses recursive templates to build the polynomial evaluation expression at compile time and relies on C++14 to be `constexpr`. I was wondering if anybody could think of a good way to remove the recursive template, perhaps using C++17. The code that exercises the template uses the `__uint128_t` type from clang and gcc.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template <typename X_t, typename Coeff_1_T>
constexpr auto poly_eval_accum(const X_t &x, const Coeff_1_T &c1)
{
    return ::std::pair<X_t, Coeff_1_T>(x, c1);
}

template <typename X_t, typename Coeff_1_T, typename... Coeff_TList>
constexpr auto poly_eval_accum(const X_t &x, const Coeff_1_T &c1, const Coeff_TList &... coeffs)
{
    const auto &tmp_result = poly_eval_accum(x, coeffs...);
    auto saved = tmp_result.second + tmp_result.first * c1;
    return ::std::pair<X_t, decltype(saved)>(tmp_result.first * x, saved);
}

template <typename X_t, typename... Coeff_TList>
constexpr auto poly_eval(const X_t &x, const Coeff_TList &... coeffs)
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(coeffs) > 0,
                  "Must have at least one coefficient.");
    return poly_eval_accum(x, coeffs...).second;
}

// This is just a test function to exercise the template.
__uint128_t multiply_lots(__uint128_t num, __uint128_t n2)
{
    const __uint128_t cf = 5;
    return poly_eval(cf, num, n2, 10);
}

// This is just a test function to exercise the template to make sure
// it computes the result at compile time.
__uint128_t eval_const()
{
    return poly_eval(5, 1, -2, 1);
}
```

Also, am I doing anything wrong here?

-------- Comments on Answers --------

There are two excellent answers down below. One is [clear and terse, but may not handle certain situations involving complex types (expression trees, matrices, etc..) well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47446154/167958), though it does a fair job. It also relies on the somewhat obscure , operator.

The other is less terse, but still [much clearer than my original recursive template, and it handles types just as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47446645/167958). It expands out to 'cn + x * (cn-1 + x * (cn-2 ...' whereas my recursive version expands out to `cn + x * cn-1 + x * x * cn-2 ...`. For most reasonable types they should be equivalent, and the answer can easily be modified to expand out to what my recursive one expands to.

I picked the first answer because it was 1st and its terseness is more within the spirit of my original question. But, if I were to choose a version for production, I'd choose the second.

Comment: It'd be nice to include a textual description of what the function is supposed to do.

Comment: @JohnZwinck - I added a paragraph about that.

Comment: If you assume that the coefficients can be coerced into a cheap-to-copy common type, you can just smash the parameter pack into an array and use familiar tools like loops and indexing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the power of comma operator (and C++17 folding, obviously), I suppose you can write `poly_eval()` as follows

```
template <typename X_t, typename C_t, typename ... Cs_t>
constexpr auto poly_eval (X_t const & x, C_t a, Cs_t const & ... cs)
 {
   ( (a *= x, a += cs), ..., (void)0 );

   return a;
 }
```

trowing away `poly_eval_accum()`.

Observe that the first coefficient if explicated, so you can delete also the `static_assert()` and is passed by copy, and become the accumulator.

**-- EDIT --**

Added an alternative version to solve the problem of the return type using <s>`std::common_type`</s> a `decltype()` of an expression, as the OP suggested; in this version `a` is a constant reference again.

```
template <typename X_t, typename C_t, typename ... Cs_t>
constexpr auto poly_eval (X_t const & x, C_t const & c1, Cs_t const & ... cs)
 {
   decltype(((x * c1) + ... + (x * cs))) ret { c1 };

   ( (ret *= x, ret += cs), ..., (void)0 );

   return ret;
 }
```

**-- EDIT 2 --**

Bonus answer: it's possible avoid the recursion also in C++14 using the power of the comma operator (again) and initializing an unused C-style array of integers

```
template <typename X_t, typename C_t, typename ... Cs_t>
constexpr auto poly_eval (X_t const & x, C_t const & a, Cs_t const & ... cs)
 {
   using unused = int[];

   std::common_type_t<decltype(x * a), decltype(x * cs)...>  ret { a };

   (void)unused { 0, (ret *= x, ret += cs)... };

   return ret;
 }
```

Comment: Oh, that's nifty. I've forgotten, but I suppose the `,` operator is a sequence point? Though I know the evaluation rules have gotten stronger in C++17, I think the sequence point idea is still honored, right?

Comment: Also, wouldn't this require at least two coefficients then? Oh, I guess the fold expression is just ignored if `sizeof...(cs)` is 0.

Comment: @Omnifarious - as far I know the comma **operator** is a sequence point; the sequence point problem with the comma is when used to separate the argument calling a function; in that case is undefined the order of evaluation but, in that case, the comma is a separator, not an operator.

Comment: Yep, that's what I thought. Yes, I know the distinction between the comma operator and it's use as a separator in function and template arguments. One thing yours doesn't do is manage the return type in the same way mine does. But that's OK. It's not too hard to fix yours. The comma operator insight is the key here, and I wish I'd thought of it.

Comment: @Omnifarious - you're right: in case of `sizeof...(cs) == 0`, my code doesn't compile; answer modified (added a `, (void)0` term in folding) to accept an empty variadic pack.

Comment: @max66 But is your code correct if `sizeof...(cs) == 0`? It would seem that the first coefficient gets multiplied by `x`. But when you only have 1 coefficient, the result should be just that coefficient. Rather, the accumulator should start out zero, and all the coefficients (including the first one) should be passed in `cs`.

Comment: I used your insight and modified my question to include your answer plus a twist or two of my own.

Comment: @oisyn - no, isn't multiplied by `x` because `sizeof...(cs) == 0`; the fold expression become `( (void)0 );`

Comment: @max66 Ah yes you're totally right. There is of course nothing to expand if `cs` is empty.

Comment: @oisyn - exactly; my initial code was wrong (in case `sizeof...(cs) == 0`) because was expanded to nothing; the added `(void)0` save the case.

Comment: @Omnifarious - sorry... I'm not an expert of this part of language but... your return type problem, isn't works for `std::common_type`? Answer improved trying to simplify your new code.

Comment: I think I know what @Omnifarious is getting at. Let me write up an answer that should solve that problem.

Comment: @max66 - I think that could solve the problem if you used `decltype(x * C_t), decltype(x * Cs_t)...>` as the argument for std::common_type instead. Though, someone might define a type that promoted on operator + to something that wasn't the type of either of the two operands. One thing, for example, is it would be fun if this worked for any type that satisfied the requirement to be considered a mathematical field.

Comment: If x were a scalar for example, and each of the coefficients were a matrix. The result of adding them all together could be defined a matrix who's dimensions were the max for any given dimension in the coefficients. That could result in a matrix that, for each coefficient, is larger in at least one dimension, so it wouldn't be the same type as any of the coefficients.

Comment: @Omnifarious - I see... yes, using `decltype()` of the products is better (modified) but I understand the problem: for basic arithmetic types this should works but nothing guaranteed that works with complex types.

Comment: @max66 - Modified my version again to include your fold expression trick for transparently handling the `sizeof...(cs) == 0` case.

Comment: @Omnifarious - I don't know if you're interested but... added a C++14 version of this solution

Comment: I am, and that's nifty. A good compiler could optimize that away.

Answer (score 3):

A great answer is supplied above, but it requires a common return type and will therefore not work if you are, say, building a compile time expression tree.

What we need is some way to have a fold expression that both does the multiply with the value at the evaluation point `x` and add a coefficient at each iteration, in order to eventually end up with an expression like: `(((c0) * x + c1) * x + c2) * x + c3`. This is (I think) not possible with a fold expression directly, but we can define a special type that overloads a binary operator and does the necessary calculations.

```
template<class M, class T>
struct MultiplyAdder
{
    M mul;
    T acc;
    constexpr MultiplyAdder(M m, T a) : mul(m), acc(a) { }
};

template<class M, class T, class U>
constexpr auto operator<<(const MultiplyAdder<M,T>& ma, const U& u)
{
    return MultiplyAdder(ma.mul, ma.acc * ma.mul + u);
}

template <typename X_t, typename C_t, typename... Coeff_TList>
constexpr auto poly_eval(const X_t &x, const C_t &a, const Coeff_TList &... coeffs)
{
    return (MultiplyAdder(x, a) << ... << coeffs).acc;
}
```

As a bonus, this solution also ticks C++17's 'automatic class template argument deduction' box ;)

**Edit:** Oops, argument deduction wasn't working inside `MultiplyAdder<>::operator<<()`, because `MultiplyAdder` refers to its own template-id rather than its template-name. I've added a namespace specifier, but that unfortunately makes it dependent on its own namespace. There must be a way to refer to its actual template-name, but I can't think of any without resorting to template aliases.

**Edit2:** Fixed it by making `operator<<()` a non-member.

Comment: This is easier to understand than my original code. And it handles types better than my version of the code of @max66. It's still wordier than his. But the fact that it handles types well is, IMHO, enough to make up for it. I think it handles types even better than my modified version.

Comment: yes: this handles the problem of the return type in a rigorous way.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This was interesting and educational. I'm tempted to switch to accepting your answer, but I settled for just pointing to it and extolling it in my answer. :-) Good on you for catching the deduction error. I should've noticed that. :-)